# How to Automate package migrations in Maximo Manage Application from backend in Maximo 8.X Versions?

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Is there any way we can perform the deployments/migrations in Maximo Manage Application (8.X Vesion) from backend. Since it is a SaaS Product, the only available way to perform deployment currently is using Maximo Migration Manager UI Screen (By creating & Distributing as Packages). Please note that I don't see any REST API, CLI Commands, Scripts available in WIKI Pages to achieve the same.

The Deployment approach using Migration Manager UI is a manual process, and there are chances of human errors. And if there are more number of changes to be deployed, then the deployment duration is more.